Where does the formula for complex powers come from
I was always taught powers (for example $x^2$) as how many times one has to multiply the number by itself (so for $x^2$ we have to multiply $x$ by itself $2$ times, meaning $x^2 = x \cdot x$.
I am now learning complex numbers, and here the complex powers are defined using both the exponential function and complex logharitms:
$$ z^c = e^{c \ln z}$$
Where does that formula come from? And how does it relate to the normal intuition for powers?

Is it so surprising?  For a positive real $z$, we have $c\ln z=ln (z^c)$ and $\exp(\ln (z^c))=z^c$ so in this case the definition coincides with the old one.  You need something more than the old $z^2=z\times z$ principle though...how could you interpret something like $(1+i)^{3+2i}$ that way?

What's your intuition for $x^{\sqrt2}$, Gronn? or for $x^{\pi}$? It's not complex exponents that are the actual problem, is it?

Observe that $x = e^{(\ln{x})}$, since the logarithm is the inverse of the exponential. So the equality $z^c = e^{ln{z^c}} = e^{cln{z}}$ is trivial using simple properties of logarithms. But why do we need the number $e$ to do powers on complex numbers? By Euler's formula, we have that:
$$
e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x}
$$
So it is easy to get the value of $e$ to an imaginary number. For example, if you have $(1+i)^{(2+2i)}$ using Euler's formula we have that
$$
(1+i)^{(2+2i)} = (1+i)^2\cdot(i+1)^{2i} = (1+i)^2\cdot e^{\ln{(1+i)}2i}
$$
And we can compute the exponential by plugging $x = 2\ln(1+i)$ into euler's formula
If you need, I can provide the proof for the identity.
PS: from $e^{ix} = \cos{x} + i\sin{x}$ you can deduce Euler's identity $e^{\pi i} +1 = 0$

Thank you for a good explaination!

@Gronnmann you are welcome my friend
